# How to convert input Date string into browser specific timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Need help to make the incoming Date String (for eg, 2016-01-09 22:26:32.348) into time specific to each browser accessing the webpage from different location.

I am getting '2016-01-09 22:26:32.348' date string from the server. Which I am looking to convert it to time specific to country from where its get accessed from. So if the I am getting '2016-01-09 22:26:32.348' date from the server running in IST, and if the page is accessed from tokyo, then it should show 2016-01-10 1:56:32.232 (approx).

If I am having time in millisec (long value), then the javascript Date is coverting it without any problem. Is this possible with javascript, without using any other js library (moment.js)

Comment: If the server code belongs to you, you should send the date in a universal format such as ISO 8601 (e.g. "2016-01-08T19:20:30.45+01:00"). Then, you can use javascript `Date` function as usual.

Comment: by only using native date that cant be possible.better use moment and moment timezone both are awesome libraries for date related stuffs.there will be lot of edge cases.for date related stuffs moment should be used

Comment: and also the time coming from server should be in UTC format which can be easily converted to corresponding time zone.

Comment: @ardabeyazoglu The server is in production, so not possible to add the changes.

Comment: @Ayush then you cant do it with that format as your browser can not detect in which timezone it is created.

Comment: It's unclear where you are wanting to write this code.  If it's server side (as in node.js) then you can't do this without a library and knowing the specific timezone. If it's client-side, then just do `new Date(yourDateString).toISOString()` and send that to the server.

Comment: @ardabeyazoglu Thank you for help.